# Assign int value to char

Tags: types, d

While learning C++ and D I am trying to compare the ease of use by testing some code in both languages.

So, in C++ I have something like this (not showing complete C++ code it's just for the demo):

```
char src[] = "some10char";
char des[];

for (int i=0; i<1000; i++)
{
    src[9] = '0' + i % (126 - '0');
    des = src;
}
```

In the 'pseudo' above, first line in the body of for loop not only assigns the `int` value, but also tries to avoid unprintable values.

**How could I do same in D?**

So far I have managed to cast `int` to `char` and I don't know if I have made it correctly:

```
char[] src = "some10char".dup;
char[] dst;

for (int i=0; i<1000; i++)
{   
    if (i<15) 
        src[src.length-1] = cast(char)(i+15);
    else
        src[src.length-1] = cast(char)(i);

    dst = src.dup // testing also dst = src;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add and substract from a character litteral in D, just as in your c++ sample, eg:

```
import std.stdio;

char[] str;

void main(string[] args)
{
    for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
    {
        str ~= cast(char)( i % (0x7F - '0') + '0') ;
    }
    writeln(str);
}
```

to print only ascii characters over `0` and less than `0x7F`. The character is implicitly converted to an int and the final operation on `i` (which itself gives an `int`) is then explicitely casted to a `char` (so modulo/mask by 0xFF).

Comment: thanks @Nt by the way if i try copying `dst=src` this won't work in a loop as i try array of structs with `char[]` as field.. but `dst=src.dup` does... so  `~= `  is actually executing `.dup`?

Comment: No the __~=__ operator is used to concatenate in the target array. For each iteration a char is appended.

Answer (score 4):

More idiomatic D code:

```d
char[] source = "some10char".dup; // or cast(char[])"some10char";
char[] destination; // = new char[source.length];

foreach (i; 0 .. 1000)
{
    source[$ - 1] = cast(char)('0' + i % (126 - '0'));

    destination = source.dup; // dup will allocate every time
    //destination[] = source[]; // copying, but destination must have same length as source
}
```

Comment: i guess the `x[] = y[]` will be faster but not as safe as `x=y.dup` and in all cases there's no need to use `free` ?

Comment: @RajFelix Which is strange. Because @Nestedtype suggests using `~`, while it has no meaning in the context of your question.

Comment: @LoneXcoder Much faster as every call to `dup` [will allocate](http://dlang.org/arrays.html#resize) new array. (Same as `~=` when `.capacity` is 0.)

Comment: yes it just worked.. as a hack `~=`  i can now understand that `.dup` is a proper way, i just think it's not polite to take a trophy back (: what would u do ?

Comment: by the way if the length of the char[] of destination is unknown, it seem not to work when `dst[]=src[]` as it compiles but gives an out of range or something for the assignmet, as the dst[] is never initialized in my case before the copying... is that correct ?

Comment: @RajFelix I've mentioned it in the comments in the code.